# `composer update` doesn't update to the latest version

Tags: php, git, laravel, composer-php

In my `composer.json` I have

```
"require": {
    . . .
    "unisharp/laravel-filemanager": "~1.8"
}
```

Currently, the latest version is [v1.8.2.2](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/releases) and after running the `composer update` command I have it installed on my localhost project (everything is OK).

I have pushed (`git push origin master`) from localhost to the remote repo on Bitbucket, and via SSH I have connected to the web server and cloned (`git clone ...`) it from that remote repo.

Now, when I run `composer update` (on web server) - it installs **v1.8.0** which has some **bug**. After that, when I try again to run `composer update` - I get:

```
Nothing to install or update
```

... but it's still **v1.8.0** (not *v1.8.2.2* like it is on localhost).

So, I have identical project with identical composer.json on my localhost and on live server but, for some reason, localhost has the latest version of the package and live version has the old version with bug and `composer update` doesn't update it.

Do you know why this is happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: You should run `composer update` locally and commit your `composer.lock` file to your version control. You should then run a `composer install` on your server to pull in the dependencies which are detailed in the `composer.lock` file.

Comment: After running `composer update`, do you run `php artisan vendor:publish`?

Comment: How will `php artisan vendor:publish` update the package version?

Comment: @Jonathon I made a mistake because I didn't run `install` first but `update` (which looks composer.json, not composer.lock). Now when I did `composer install` first - everything is OK. If you can - post your comment as _answer_ so I can check it.

Comment: Sure thing, added now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should run `composer update` locally. This will update `composer.lock` with the versions of all the packages you have installed. You should commit your `composer.lock` file to your version control.

On your server, once you've updated your files you should then run a `composer install` so Composer can update its dependencies to match those specified in your `composer.lock` file.

Comment: Thank you, was wondering how to change composer packages and update the server without updating version, wanted to remove some packages.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent two hours debugging this.  Turns out the problem was that there was a "version" tag in the composer.json file.

When there is a version tag there, that version will be used in priority above any git tag version that you apply.